# Attach div to image

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to attach a div to an image? As in, to make the div follow the image? I have a web app where the user can click on a part of the page, and the image moves to it with easing. I'd like a speech bubble to follow the image and remain above it, but I'm having trouble finding out what this requires.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: There is no code as such. I was wondering if it's at all possible to even attach a div to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I should do this, I would make a Div containing your image and the div of the speech bubble.

```
<div class="topelement">
  <img src="#" />
  <div class="speechbubble"></div>
</div>
```

Then when the user clicks on the certain part of the page, you can move the div with de class "topelement".

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

If this is the element which user needs to clicks:

```
 <div id="showImage">
    Show the image
  </div>
```

Once the user clicks that, the below slider will be shown

```
<div class="divSlider">
  <img src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33100000/justin-bieber-2013-justin-bieber-33194067-1295-1500.jpg"  />
  <div class="speechbubble">Your bubble message here!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.speechbubble {
  background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/k/N/x/a/k/dialog-bubble-rectangle-md.png");
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: red;
}
.divSlider {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

By default am hiding the div in CSS itself.

now jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#showImage").click(function(){
      $(".divSlider").fadeIn(2000);  
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/kolor/1/edit)